# IBM ODM start up error Could not lookup datasource named 'jdbc/ilogDataSource'

Tags: ibm-odm

I am learning ODM (Operational Decision Manager) and installed docker, pulled the image via docker pull.  I then started the docker image with:

docker run -e LICENSE=accept  -m 2048M --memory-reservation 2048M -p 9060:9060 -p 9443:9443 -v $PWD:/config/dbdata/ -e SAMPLE=false  ibmcom/odm:8.10

Watching the console I'm getting this error

[ERROR   ] An error occurs when creating the session [jdbc/ilogDataSource]. Database set up will stop.  Could not lookup datasource named 'jdbc/ilogDataSource'